# Setting after content in html with angularjs?

Tags: css, angularjs

If I have the following CSS:

```
.myStyle {
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.myStyle:after {
    content: "My Content";
}
```

And the following html:

```
<div class="myStyle">
    Set content for after?
</div>
```

I would like to set the `content` for `after` with a value from my angularjs `{{ client.Name }}`.

Is this possible?  How?

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Why not just append it ?

Comment: Because I want to use this `after` with a much more complicated style: `.test:after {
  content: "Test";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #4f4f4f;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
          border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
}`

Comment: so ? just add another style

Comment: Can you provide an example?  At least I can mark it as an answer then.

Comment: `<div class="myStyle">blah</div><div class="afterMyStyle">{{ client.Name }}</div>`

Comment: Yeah.  I dont know why I didnt think of that :P thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create an element after it

```
<div class="myStyle">blah</div><div class="afterMyStyle">{{ client.Name }}</div>
```